# Highcharts chart not displaying as an area chart even after specifying type as area

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a chart that updates every second with data from server but the chart doesn't seem to be displaying as an area chart, of which I specified the series type as area but it still doesn't display as an area chart. I did notice that if I initialize the data in the series (with some random data) on creating the chart it works but the chart won't be accurate because the data is not from the server.

Here's the code:

```
function createChart(asset, name) {
      chart = new Highcharts.stockChart('chart', {
        chart: {
            events: {
                load: function() {
                  setTimeout(function() {
                    interval = setInterval(function(){
                      requestData(asset, name)
                    }, 1000);
                  }, 1000);
                }
              }
          },
        rangeSelector: {
            buttons: [{
                count: 1,
                type: 'minute',
                text: '1M'
            }],
            inputEnabled: false,
            selected: 0
        },
        navigator: {
          enabled: false
        },
        title: {
            text: name
        },
        xAxis: {
          type: 'datetime',
          tickPixelInterval: 150,
          //tickPixelInterval: 3600
        },
        yAxis: {
            allowDecimals: true,
            title: {
                text: 'Values'
            },
            labels: {
               //format: '{value: .2f}'
            },
            opposite: false,
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                dashStyle: 'longdashdot',
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Price',
            type: 'area',
            color: '#2D2E2F',
            data: []
        }]
      });
  }

function requestData(asset, name) {
    $.ajax({
      url:' process_ajax.php',
      data: {
         action: 'get_asset_data',
         asset: asset
      },
      success: function(res) {
        if (res.success) {
          var series = chart.series[0],
              shift = series.data.length > 20;
         chart.yAxis[0].plotLinesAndBands[0].options.value = res.data.price;
              chart.yAxis[0].setExtremes(res.data.low, res.data.high);
              chart.series[0].addPoint([res.data.time, res.data.price], true, shift);
        }
      },
      cache: false
    });
  }
```

PS: The chart updates fine but the issue is getting it to display as an area chart.

EDIT:

Thanks, I've solved it, the problem was stemming from my data, the y axis data is being received as a string instead of a number, to solve it I just type casted the data to number.

Comment: I don't see where you're specifying that it's an area chart (I'm sure I'm just missing it though); try adding type: area to the chart parameter? ie `chart: { events: {...}, type: 'area'}` .... EDIT: Ah, I see, you've specified it in 'series'. Nonetheless, try specifying in 'chart'.

Comment: Yeah thanks, I specified it in 'chart' but still nothing, it just updates as usual without the area.

Comment: What does your data look like? Can you set up a fiddle showing the issue?

Comment: Can you paste a sample of your data? And also, you have a race condition in your code - interval <-> ajax - it should be taken care of.